# Problema na busca multitabela com php

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca, tabela-html

Preciso fazer com que meu script faça busca em várias tabelas dentro do mesmo banco. Eu não quero que uma tabela tenha relação com outra ou que necessáriamente sejam combinadas, apenas preciso que o sistema de busca do site busque a palavra digitada pelo usuário em todas as tabelas do banco.

Banco X com 35 tabelas quando o usuário digitar uma palavra preciso que esta palavra seja procurada em todas as 35 tabelas do banco e todos os resultados na coluna conteúdo das 35 tabelas sejam exbidos para o usuário.

Eu não posso utilizar nenhuma outra tecnologia, linguagem ou plataforma que não seja PHP e MySQL.

Abaixo segue o código do meu script de busca resultdo.php:

```js
<?php
 $db = @mysql_connect("meu host", "meu banco", "minha senha") or die("Erro de conexão: ".mysql_error());
 @mysql_select_db("meu banco", $db) or die("Erro de seleção do DB: ".mysql_error());
?>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['botao'])){
 $busca = $_POST['busca'];
 if($busca == "" or $busca == " "){
 header('location:http://www.meudominio.com.br/digitealgoparaabusca.php'); 
 }else{
 $busca_dividida = explode(' ',$busca);
 $quant = count($busca_dividida);
 $id_mostrado = array("");
 for($i=0;$i<$quant;$i++){
 $pesquisa = $busca_dividida[$i];
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM busca WHERE conteudo REGEXP '".str_replace(' ','|',$busca)."'");
 $quant_campos = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if($quant_campos == 0){ 
 header('location:http://www.meudominio.com.br/nenhumresultado.php'); 
 }else{
 while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $id = $linha['id'];
 $titulo = $linha['titulo'];
 $conteudo = $linha['conteudo'];
 if(!array_search($id, $id_mostrado)){
 echo "<div class='resultado'>
 <p>".$conteudo."</p>
 </div>
 <br />
 "; 
 array_push($id_mostrado, $id);
 }
 }//do while
 }//do else
 //for($i;$i<count($id_mostrado);$i++){
 //echo $id_mostrado[$i]."<br />";
 //}
 }//do for
 }//so else campo vazio
 }//do if botão pressionado
 ?>
```

Peço vossa ajuda com esse probelma.

Obrigado desde já,

Phil